# Unity 2D Tutorial 'Kit Tools'

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I've been trying to follow the Unity tutorial for the 2D game kit, but I can't find the 'Kit tools' button on the menu. I've been trying to find answers, but couldn't. The button simply isn't there. I was wondering if I was importing it wrong, or something else. Thank you.

Comment: Which menu? What is this kit tools for? Give more details so we can help

Comment: The top menu that says file, edit, etc. This is for the Unity 2D game kit tutorial, where the first step requires the "tool kit" button on the top. However, i cant find it. Thank you

Comment: Have you downloaded and imported the project of the tutorial successfully? This is not a default menu, it will only show up if you have the project assets.

Comment: I thought i did. However, there is a high chance i messed up. I looked at videos of this kit, but none showed the downloading and importing process, so i am unable to find out what i did wrong

Comment: Is there anything in your Assets folder under the Project tab in the editor?

Comment: There is the 2DGameKit folder. But it doesnt contain the first step of the tutorial. Sorry if im missing something obvious, by the way. I appreciate your time spent with me

Comment: This is odd. Try to create a new empty project and import the assets directly from Asset Store. Inside Unity, go to Window > Asset Store, search for 2D Game Kit, download it and click on Import. Don't know how you did it at the first time, but this way should work. I've tried myself and the menu is there

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! I'm going to write an answer so you can accept

Comment: It didn't work again... But I'll retry it again.

Comment: I found WHY it wasn't working. The Kit wasn't updated to the latest Unity version I'm using. It should work now though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the example project wasn't imported correctly. Try to create a new empty project and import the assets directly from Asset Store. Inside Unity, go to `Window > Asset Store`, search for **2D Game Kit**, download it and click on Import. Don't know how you did it at the first time, but this way should work. I've tried myself and the menu is there.